# Is $C$ then weakly compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, let $C\subset K\subset X$ such that $C$ is closed and $K$ is weakly compact. Is $C$ then weakly compact ?

Comment: No, consider $C$ an ONB in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space and $K=C\cup\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

No. For instance, consider $K$ the closed unit ball of a reflexive, infinite-dimensional Banach space and $C$ the unit sphere. $C$ is weakly dense in $K$, and therefore it is not weakly closed in $K$. However, the weak topology is Hausdorff.